# Report studio: keep list in one page in pdf

Tags: pdf, report, cognos

I have this list on a report that exceeds one page because it has a lot of rows. Instead of having it split into two pages I want the second part of the list to appear next to the first part, all in the same page. Both in html and pdf.

Disabled break and horizontal pagination in the list properties but did not work. Also put page break in report properties. It did improve the amount of rows that fit now but I still need to put one half of the list next to each other because I do not want it to split in many pages. Maybe there is another solution you know of.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post this from what I got to contribute if someone is looking for something similar.

If you know the amount of rows you can use a "newspaper" style report. Look it up, you'll find it simple.

Another option is to use repeater tables. I went for this one because my amount of rows was dinamic.

Hope this helps.

Regards